# Possible to Dask -ify incremental PCA or Stochastic Gradient Descent or other scikit learn partial fit algorithms

Tags: scikit-learn, pca, dask

Based on [Incremental PCA on big data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428581/incremental-pca-on-big-data) and the incremental PCA docs its suggested to use a memmap array but would it be possible to accomplish the same thing using dask?

**Update** Expanded the question to include other partial fit algorithms as the git repo for dask mentions a method of using any scikit-learn which supports partial fit but I can't seem to find documentation on it in the API. When I attempted incremental pca for an `6000x250000 float64` dask dataframe it took 8 hrs to make 9% progress on 16 core 104GB vm without adjusting the dask scheduler but I wasn't sure if it was down to my poor code or if thats what to expect with a dataset of this size. I'd welcome any advice on batch sizing for SGD even just as proof of concepthttps://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/array/learn.pyhttp://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2016/07/12/dask-learn-part-1

Answer (score 4):

The [dask.array.linalg.svd](http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.linalg.svd) function operates in parallel in small space.

The [fit and predict](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/array/learn.py) functions in dask.array support any `sklearn.Estimator` with a `partial_fit` method.

The [dask-learn](https://github.com/dask/dask-learn) project handles `partial_fit`, grid searches, pipelines, etc..   See this three part blog series by Jim Crist about the project:

1. http://jcrist.github.io/dask-sklearn-part-1.html
2. http://jcrist.github.io/dask-sklearn-part-2.html
3. http://jcrist.github.io/dask-sklearn-part-3.html

Comment: Would you have any recommendations for partition sizing ? At the moment it's looking like 1 row per partition

Comment: Please read the documentation: http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/array-creation.html#chunks