# Do you need a for loop for IncrementalPCA in order to keep constant memory usage?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pca

In the past, I've tried to use scikit-learn's IncrementalPCA in order to reduce memory usage. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31432111/10183880) as a template for my code. But as @aarslan said in the comment section: "I've noticed that the explained variance seems to decrease at every iteration." I've always suspected the last `for loop` in the given answer. So, my question is: Do I need a for loop in order to keep a constant memory usage during `partial_fit` step or `batch_size` is alone enough? Below you can find the code:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import IncrementalPCA

h5 = h5py.File('rand-1Mx1K.h5')
data = h5['data'] # it's ok, the dataset is not fetched to memory yet

n = data.shape[0] # how many rows we have in the dataset
chunk_size = 1000 # how many rows we feed to IPCA at a time, the divisor of n
icpa = IncrementalPCA(n_components=10, batch_size=16)

for i in range(0, n//chunk_size):
    ipca.partial_fit(data[i*chunk_size : (i+1)*chunk_size])
```

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but yes, the for-loop is needed.  The `batch_size=` parameter is only used with the `.fit()` method, not with `.partial_fit()`.

Scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA.fit):

> **batch_size : int, default=None**
>
> The number of samples to use for each batch. Only used when calling fit.